# How to extract all email addresses in the body from an eml file

Tags: python, email, eml

I am working on a project that looks in a mailbox and extract data from mails.

I want to extract all email addressess found in the mail body.

Extract email addresses:

```
# Python script to extract email addresses from email messages / eml
# Comment from JNevill solved the final bit
import os
import re
from email import policy
from email.parser import BytesParser

emaillocation = os.chdir(r"\\10.21.1.236\websites\vaccinatieplanner\mail\stroomz\onbezorgd")
emaillist = []

for emailmessage in os.listdir(emaillocation):
    with open(f'{emailmessage}', 'rb') as em:
        msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(em)
    emailmsgraw = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain', 'html'))
    emailmsg = emailmsgraw.get_content()
    emaillist.extend(re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', emailmsg))

print(emaillist)
```

Comment: Instead of `re.search` and everything following, just `emaillist.extend(re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', emailmsg))` should do the trick. (edited to use `list.extend()` to account for multiple files)

Comment: That is awesome! That worked and thanks for you valueable learning lesson!

Answer (score 0):

Answered and solved with the help of the comment of JNevill

```
# Python script to extract email addresses from email messages / eml
# Comment from JNevill solved the final bit
import os
import re
from email import policy
from email.parser import BytesParser

emaillocation = os.chdir(r"\\10.21.1.236\websites\vaccinatieplanner\mail\stroomz\onbezorgd")
emaillist = []

for emailmessage in os.listdir(emaillocation):
    with open(f'{emailmessage}', 'rb') as em:
        msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(em)
    emailmsgraw = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain', 'html'))
    emailmsg = emailmsgraw.get_content()
    emaillist.extend(re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', emailmsg))

print(emaillist)
```